# Is there a way to specify write consistency level when using spring data's ElasticSearchTemplate?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

when using the elastic search java client it is possible to specify the write consistency level and timeout for each query:

---

```
        final IndexRequestBuilder indexRequestBuilder = client.prepareIndex("myIndex", "myType");
        indexRequestBuilder.setConsistencyLevel(WriteConsistencyLevel.ALL);
        indexRequestBuilder.setTimeout(TimeValue.timeValueMillis(500));

        final XContentBuilder sourceBuilder = .....

        indexRequestBuilder.setSource(sourceBuilder).execute().actionGet();
```

---

I did not find an API to do the same with Spring Data's ElasticSearchTemplate.

Do you know if there is a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after checking with the spring folks at devoxx.be it looks like there isn't a way to specify write consistency and timeout per query with SpringData's ElasticSearchTemplate.