# Read time out in spring data elasticsearch

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

Is it possible to set readTimeout in spring data elasticsearch ?

Scenario : my application is trying to query elasticsearch using elasticsearch template , but sometimes it takes lot off time and request gets piled up.
Plz don't confuse it with client ping timeout.
There are like 2-3 Cr documents in elasticsearch and it is like 100 rps on my application.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

there isn't a way to specify write timeout per query with SpringData's ElasticSearchTemplate .
Please check this answer :-
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40558236/2357869

You can use Elastic search core java api for this, 
try to use this class :- 
org.elasticsearch.action.ActionFuture.actionGet

```
SearchRequestBuilder countRequestBuilder = esClient.prepareSearch("index").setTypes("type").setQuery(searchQuery);
        SearchResponse response = countRequestBuilder.execute().actionGet(time_out, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a property that can be used for this:

```
spring.elasticsearch.jest.connection-timeout=3000 # Connection timeout in milliseconds.
spring.elasticsearch.jest.multi-threaded=true # Enable connection requests from multiple execution threads.
```

Should work in Spring Boot in yml style too